# Is there is a faster alternative for Integer.toString(myInt).getBytes(US_ASCII)?

Tags: java

User sends me `byte / short / int / long` value. I have to send it as the part of POST HTTP request and I have to send number as String.

So right now I do the next:

```
//simplified version
byte[] data = Integer.toString(myInt).getBytes(US_ASCII);
sendPost(data);
```

I'm looking for faster alternative for

```
Integer.toString(myInt).getBytes(US_ASCII);
```

Because this flow creates `char[]`, `String` and `byte[]` objects. While I need only `byte[]`. I wonder if there is any faster/better alternative to this.

Comment: So for `int 123` you want `byte[] {1, 2, 3}`?

Comment: @LutzHorn byte[] {31, 32, 33} to be precise in HEX

Comment: Then you will have to turn the `int` into a `String` first.

Comment: Well, this is what code already does. Question is about faster alternative without creating intermediate objects. Something like Integer.toBytesAsStringValue(myInt)

Comment: I don't think something like this exists in the JDK. Are you sure this is code worth optimizing?

Comment: Yes. This is JDBC driver and it does setInt() for batch inserts. Where Integer is translated to String. On huge batches those allocations are main bottleneck.

Comment: Maybe you can do some caching when your inputs are often the same?

Comment: @Matthias cache wont work for the random input or floating point number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions. I decided to go through the easiest possible way. I just copied the methods from the `Integer.toString()` and inlined into my code with the minimal modifications. I didn't perform exact benchmark, however, for JDBC driver I writing I got 2x performance boost due to this change. Here is the final solution:

```
private static final byte[] DigitTens = {
        '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
        '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
        '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
        '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6',
        '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7',
        '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8',
        '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9',
};

private static final byte[] DigitOnes = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
};

public byte[] intAsStringToBytes(int i) {
    int size = stringSize(i);
    byte[] buf = new byte[size];
    getChars(i, size, buf);
    return buf;
}

private static int stringSize(int x) {
    int d = 1;
    if (x >= 0) {
        d = 0;
        x = -x;
    }
    int p = -10;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        if (x > p) {
            return i + d;
        }
        p = 10 * p;
    }
    return 10 + d;
}

private static void getChars(int i, int index, byte[] buf) {
    int q, r;
    int charPos = index;

    boolean negative = i < 0;
    if (!negative) {
        i = -i;
    }

    // Generate two digits per iteration
    while (i <= -100) {
        q = i / 100;
        r = (q * 100) - i;
        i = q;
        buf[--charPos] = DigitOnes[r];
        buf[--charPos] = DigitTens[r];
    }

    // We know there are at most two digits left at this point.
    q = i / 10;
    r = (q * 10) - i;
    buf[--charPos] = (byte) ('0' + r);

    // Whatever left is the remaining digit.
    if (q < 0) {
        buf[--charPos] = (byte) ('0' - q);
    }

    if (negative) {
        buf[--charPos] = (byte) '-';
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding unnecessary objects obviously improves performance.
In the context of Clickhouse JDBC driver, I also suggest considering do not create separate byte[] array for each int or other variables. Use one byte[] array (like in StringBuilder) for the whole SQL request and use "append" style to fill it.

Comment: Yes, this is something I'm actually working within clickhouse4j.

Answer (score 2):

This solution quite straightforward.

```
import java.util.Arrays; // Needed only for demo purposes

public class LongToBytes
{
  private static final byte ZERO = '0';
  private static final byte MINUS = '-';

  public static byte[] convert(long value)
  {
    // -------------------------------------
    // Manage some particular value directly
    // abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) remains negative
    // -------------------------------------
    if ((value >= 0) && (value < 10))
      return (new byte[]{(byte)(ZERO + value)});
    else if ((value > -10) && (value < 0))
      return (new byte[] {MINUS, (byte)(ZERO - value)});
    else if (value == Long.MIN_VALUE)
      return (Long.toString(value).getBytes());

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize result
    // The longest value (Long.MIN_VALUE+1) is composed of 20 characters
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------
    byte[] array;
    array = new byte[20];

    // ---------------------------
    // Keep track of eventual sign
    // ---------------------------
    boolean negative;
    negative = (value < 0);
    if (negative)
      value = -value;

    // ----------------------
    // Fill array (backwards)
    // ----------------------
    int size;
    size = 0;
    while (value > 0)
    {
      array[size] = (byte)((value % 10) + ZERO);
      size++;
      value /= 10;
    }

    // -------------------
    // Add sign eventually
    // -------------------
    if (negative)
    {
      array[size] = MINUS;
      size++;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Compose result, giving it the correct length and reversing it
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    byte[] result;
    int    counter;
    result = new byte[size];
    for (counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
      result[size - counter - 1] = array[counter];

    // ----
    // Done
    // ----
    return (result);

  } // convert

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      long value;
      value = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
      System.out.println(value);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(convert(value)));
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

} // class LongToBytes
```

**UPDATE**
I checked the performance calling both ways (the method here above and `Long.toString().getBytes()`) separately in a loop over 100.000.000, using `System.nanoTime()` as a stopwatch.

Passing 0, the method above is about 500 times faster.
Relatively small values (between -10.000 and 10.000) have a gain of about 60%.
Huge values (near Long.MIN_VALUE and Long.MAX_VALUE) have a gain of about 40%.

**UPDATE 2**
Managing specific values (between -9 and 9 and the value Long.MIN_VALUE) separately, things get slightly better.
I updated the method's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

just an idea

```
int digits = getNumberOfDifits(number);

byte[] out = new byte[digits];

for (int j = digits - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    int rem = number % 10;
    out[j] = getByteForDigit(rem);
    number = number / 10;
}

return out
```

no auxiliary objects in heap, everything processed in stack

Comment: Actually something similar is done within Integer.getChars()  but it is a bit more complex. I think I'll move in this way and will copy JDK method and apply to my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility. This is consistently faster that the `Integer.toString()` approach.

```java
   public static byte[] getBytes(long value) {
      int sign = 0;
      if (value < 0) {
         sign = 1;
         value = -value;
      }

      long temp = 10L;
      int chars = 1;
      for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
         if (value < temp) {
            chars = i + sign;
            break;
         }
         temp *= 10;
      }


      byte[] bytes = new byte[chars];

      int i = 0;
      while (value > 0) {
         bytes[chars - i - 1] = (byte) ((value % 10) + '0');
         value /= 10;
         i++;
      }

      if (sign == 1) {
         bytes[0] = '-';
      }
      return bytes;
   }
```

Comment: @dmitriydumanskiy I modified the digit calculation.  Seems to have improved things greatly over the log function.